# AMPscript Help for Splitting Field

Tags: marketing-cloud, split

I'm new to Marketing Cloud and not fluent with AMPscript. Can someone please help with my script to split a field and only display the venue name on the back end?

I'm getting the error message:

> A variable name is not a valid because contains illegal characters. Variable names must begin with the @ symbol followed by one or more letters, numbers, or underscores. Variable Name: @

```ampscript
%%[ 

VAR @Seminar_Name, @Seminar_Venue_Name
SET @Seminar_Name = "Seminar> Your Life. Your Legacy.> Casa Pasta" 

IF IndexOf(@Seminar_Name, ">") > 0 

THEN SET @Seminar_Venue_Name = Substring(@Seminar_Name,1,Subtract(IndexOf(@Seminar_Name,">"),1)) 

ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: What is the actual venue of the seminar in your sample above?  Casa Pasta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Casa Pasta` is the venue, you can build a rowset using the `>` as a delimiter:

```ampscript
%%[

set @seminar_name = "Seminar> Your Life. Your Legacy.> Casa Pasta"

/* split the string on every instance of ">" */
set @seminar_name_rs = buildRowsetFromString(@seminar_name, ">")

/* count how many elements are returnd */
set @rowcount = rowcount(@seminar_name_rs)

/* if there are three elements */
if @rowCount >= 3 then

  /* pick the third element*/
  set @row = row(@seminar_name_rs, 3)

  /* get the value (and trim any leading and trailing spaces */
  set @seminar_venue_name = trim(field(@row,1))

else

  /* default value if the seminar_name doesn't fit the 3 element pattern */
  set @seminar_venue_name = @seminar_name

endif

]%%
Name: %%=v(@seminar_name)=%%
<br>Venue: %%=v(@seminar_venue_name)=%%
```

**Output**

```
Name: Seminar> Your Life. Your Legacy.> Casa Pasta
Venue: Casa Pasta
```

**Try it for yourself**

- https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/2UQZDYhI

**Reference**

- [BuildRowsetFromString()](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromstring)
- [Trim()](https://ampscript.guide/trim)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!